# different behavior of method when immediately accessing the results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mapreduce, mongoid

I have a class method `Juxtaposition.generate_for(position)` on a class that I am calling from a spec. The method sets up a map reduce and calls it `map_reduce(map, reduce).out(merge: "juxtapositions")`

The position variable is defined in a let prior to the it block.

When executing if I simply call the function above (which is really only calling a map reduce on data related to the position) then tests like below fail:

```
Juxtaposition.count.should eq 1
Juxtaposition.first.value.should eq values
```

However, if I call

```
Juxtaposition.generate_for(positions).first["value"].should eq values
```

prior to the two tests then they both pass.  The above two tests also pass when I use pry and call the `generate_for` method from there.

Is there some strange behavior of map reduce in mongoid that I should be aware of? Or, is there some way to force the results into my later queries.

Comment: I guess this implies that generate_for is returning something different to what you expect.

Comment: Yeah, it's not returning anything or saving to mongodb as expected, unless I specifically ask for its values when generated.

Comment: mongo --version == 2.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was simple enough.  I just need to make sure to call find on the call to map reduce.

More specifically:

```
map_reduce(map, reduce).out(merge: "juxtapositions").first
```

or

```
map_reduce(map, reduce).out(merge: "juxtapositions").to_a
```

Without to_a or first the actual map reduce doesn't execute it seems, even if it's meant to be stored in another collection.

Comment: I think I'm having an issue similar to what you experienced in your original question. Could you elaborate on your solution?

Comment: I expanded my answer above, hopefully that helps.  If you're still not getting results, check the javascript in your map reduce.  It also seems to fail silently there if things are wrong.